# Login / Registration PHP form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

having a bit of trouble with my login / reg forms

Basically when i register (create new user) it takes me to the login.php script and not the register script.

The login form is in the "header.php" page so its at the top of every page including the register form. But dont think that would be an issue?

Register form

```
<?php 
include("config.php");
include("header.php");
?>

<div id="contentwrap">

<form name="myuserform" method="POST" action="register.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
<tr class='alt'>
<td>email address: <td><input type="text" name="email"> 
<tr class='alt'>
<td>Password: <td><input type="password" name="password">
<tr class='alt'>
<td>Your name: <td><input type="text" name="username">
<tr class='alt'>
<td><input type="submit" name="adduser" value="Sign me up!"> 
</form> 

</div>
```

Register.php

```
<?php 


if (isset($_POST['adduser']))
{
    $error = "";

    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['password']);
    $md5_pass = md5($password);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['email']);

    if (!isset($username) || empty($username) ||
        !isset($password) || empty($password) ||
        !isset($email) || empty($email))
    {
        $error = "All fields must be filled out";
    }
    else if (user_exists($connection, $username))
    {
        $error = "Username already registered";
    }
    else if (strlen($password) < 6)
    {
        $error = "Password must be at least 6 characters";
    }
    else if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) // check if email looks valid
    {
        $error = "Please enter a valid email";
    }

    if ($error == "")
    {
        //$query = "INSERT INTO users (email, password, username) VALUES ('{$email}','{$md5_pass}','{$username}')";
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email) VALUES ('{$username}','{$md5_pass}','{$email}')";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if ($result)
            echo " <b>Registered successfully!</b><br/>Please return to the <a href='index.php'>index</a> to login.";

        else
            $error = "Unable to create new user";
    }

    if ($error != "") // redo error string check since the last block may have set it
    {
        echo "Error: {$error}. Please return to the previous page.";
    }

    exit();
}
?>
```

Login.php

```
<?php
include("config.php");

if (isset($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['username']) &&
    isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='{$username}' AND password='{$password}'";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($res) >= 1)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
        if($row['rank'] == "banned")
        {
            echo "You have been banned from the site.";
            exit();
        }
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['userid'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        if($row['rank'] == "admin")
        $_SESSION['is_admin'] = true;

        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Username/password invalid. Return to the <a href='index.php'> home </a>page";
        exit();
    }
}

echo "Something went wrong, try again"; <--- this is the result im getting
?>
```

here is the login form (apart of header.php)

```
    <?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['uid']) || empty($_SESSION['uid']))
{
    echo "<form action='login.php' method='post'>
    Username: <input type='text' name='username' Placeholder='Username' style='width:100px;'/>&nbsp;
    Password: <input type='password' name='password' Placeholder='Password' style='width:100px;' />&nbsp;
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Log In' />";
    echo "<div id='freeman'>
    <a href='signup.php'> <img src='images/register.jpg' width='60px' height='60px' /> </a>
    </div>";
} else {
echo "You are logged is as {$_SESSION['username']} &bull; <a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Unsalted md5 password? ... mmmm taste the rainbow.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. In this short example you have a number of dangerous [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://bobby-tables.com/) coming from a reckless lack of [proper escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](http://laravel.com/docs/security) built-in

Comment: Using MD5 for password storage is completely inadequate and exposes your users to severe risk, especially considering how you're doing zero SQL escaping. At the very least use a recommended [password hashing](http://www.phptherightway.com/#password_hashing) method or you will end up in trouble.

Comment: @tadman in this instance - I totally agree with that sentiment ... though not necessarily Laravel ;)

Comment: @CD001 Although I've had good experience with Laravel and the documentation is very beginner friendly, I did post a link there to several others that might be better suited. We all have different needs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that when you `register` your not opening a `session` to consider the `user` as logged and acquire a session for him.

The other issue your not checking in your `login` script if the `user` already have a `session` which implies that he is already logged in